# Basename does not seem to be taken into account with matchPath in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am looking into a bug we have with react-router-dom version 5.0.0 and the active class not being applied to the active link.

It works in development when we have a basename of `/` but in our dev environment, the basename is set to `/some/basename/'.

If I call this `matchPath` directly like this:

```
matchPath("/some/basename/business", {
  exact: true,
  location: undefined,
  path: "\/business",
  strict: undefined
})
```

Then it returns null, if I call matchpath like this, it gets a match:

```
matchPath("/business", {
  exact: true,
  location: undefined,
  path: "\/business",
  strict: undefined
})
```

So it looks like `matchPath` is not using the `basename` because after trying to debug the code I see that `matchPath` calls `pathToRegexp` which creates this regex:

```
/^\/business\/?$/i
```

The code only appears to be using the `path` property and not the location.pathname.

I tried to implement my own `isActive` method to log what was going on:

```
const isActive = (match: Match<any>, historyLocation: Location) =>  {
  const basename = (window.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URI || "/") === "/" ? "" : window.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URI;
  const fullUrl = `${basename.replace(/^(.+?)\/*?$/, "$1")}${historyLocation.pathname}`;

  console.log("----------------------");
  console.log({
    basename,
    fullUrl,
    historyLocation,
    historyLocationPathName: historyLocation.pathname,
    location: window.location.pathname,
    match,
  });
  console.log("----------------------");

  if (!match) {
    return;
  }

  return window.location.pathname.startsWith(`${fullUrl}`);
};
```

`match` is always null in the environment but works fine in development.

Why would this be?

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but the docs say: "a properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash"

Comment: oh man  working on a project where this is a config value and they won’t let me change this

Comment: Well that might not be the solution, can you give it a try? for example `basename={configBasename.slice(0, -1)}`?

Comment: yes, tried that.  it’s got a <base with a forward slash also

Comment: is there anyway matchPath would not get the basename to make the comparison

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### HTML Concept

This is actually one of the great advantages of react-router, because in development stage you have no idea, where the project is going to be deployed. It might be deployed on a:

- Primary Domain
- Sub Domain
- Sub Directory

So the best approach is to provide the define all the relative URLs in a 
base URL agnostic way. `basename` in React-Router is not actually something new, and we have the `<base>` head tag in HTML:

```
<head>
   <base href="https://www.yoursite.com/some/basename/" target="https://www.yoursite.com/other/">
</head>
```

This tag means that all the relative URLs in the page will have `https://www.yoursite.com/some/basename/` added to them, such as:

```
<img src="header.jpg">
```

Will be the same as

```
<img src="https://www.yoursite.com/some/basename/header.jpg">
```

and all relative links and form actions will also have `href` attached to them.

---

#### React Router

React-Router basically uses this concept (however, not base tag), so when you set `basename` in the main ` the following elements will **know nothing** about basename:

- `<Route>`
- `<Link>`
- `<Redirect>`
- `matchPath`

so when you have a Link like this:

```
<Link to="/page2" />
```

it will actually redirect to `/some/basename/page2`.

---

#### basename

- [React-Router Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) suggests to that `A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash.` (eg. **/some/business**) . However, in most of the modern browsers, it doesn't matter at all.

---

#### matchPath

Now let's talk about the matchPath. As I said before, matchPath does not know anything about the basename, so you have these in mind:

- make sure that the input URL does **not** have basename inside it.
- Do **not** use window.location.pathname, instead use the React-Router location props

Then you should be fine. So this will always work regardless of your environment (dev/prod):

```
matchPath(props.location.pathname, {
    path: '/business',
    exact: true,
});
```

---

#### Notes

If with all these in mind, you run into some problem throughout your project (including all links, all redirects, all routes, and also matchPath), then your base basename is set wrong in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [github issue comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5000#issuecomment-295349019)

> `basename` comes from the `<base href="/foo">` HTML element, which
>   applies a `basename` to all links on the page. In that case, the rest
>   of the HTML doesn't "know" about that base URL; it's just
>   automatically prepended to any href.
>
> Similarly, the basename in Router is something the application doesn't
>   know about. It just `<Link>'s` to various routes and is unaware of the
>   `basename` being attached.

When you are using using mathPath, instead of using `window.location.pathname` if you use `location.pathname` provided by Router, you will receive the pathname that matches your route instead of the entire pathname which includes basename.

```
matchPath(location.pathname, {
  exact: true,
  location: undefined,
  path: "\/business",
  strict: undefined
})
```

and the above will return true if the path is `/some/basename/busines`